# Why pasting a text file into Excel cuts off sentence in the middle

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a script that loops through hundreds of simple text files. The script opens a file, pastes it into Excel, extracts some data, deletes the text file and moves on to the next one. It worked perfectly until few days ago, when it opened one of those files (it's happening only on that one specific file) after pasting it into Excel I've noticed that one of the lines ended up abruptly...
If I will `Debug.Print` that file I can see that everything is in there, but if I will paste it into Excel, the same line ends abruptly...
Does anyone knows what might be causing that? What's weirder, if I will manually copy and paste the text into a new text file, Excel processes that without any problem...
Below is a code that deals with those text files.

```
MyFolder = "C:\Test\"
StrFile = Dir(MyFolder & "tempfile.txt")

Open MyFolder & StrFile For Binary As #1
MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
Get #1, , MyData
Close #1
strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

LineNumber = 1
For xy = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
    Debug.Print strData(xy)  'THIS WORKS!
    Range("A" & LineNumber).Value = strData(xy) 'THIS DOESN'T!
    LineNumber = LineNumber + 1
Next xy
```

Thank you!

Comment: How many characters are you trying to write into a single cell? You do realize that Excel isn't a word processor?

Comment: There is maximum of 50 lines in each text file, and each line doesn't exceed 130 characters.  I'm extracting data from those files that are needed in that spreadsheet.

Comment: That doesn't add up. VBA thinks a cell can only hold up to 255 characters. 130 shouldn't be a problem in any way.

Comment: What is the length of what you do have `=LEN(a1)` and also Compare `len(strData(xy))` to this  https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3.  You may be better using a `textstream` and reading a line at a time, rather than doing the split after.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I know it doesn't! Hence this question.

Comment: Could there be stray `vbCr` or `vbLf` characters in the string? i.e. the strings *appear* to be cut off, but if you expand the row height they continue on a new line in the same cell?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I will try to use `textstream`. But it doesn't explains why the same text if it's manually copied and pasted into a "new" text file won't cause any problems. I did try to copy and paste it into a new txt file using VBA, but I'm getting the same results as with the original file...

Comment: If you're using text to columns in your process: Excel "remembers" the splitting process and may auto-apply it to the next set of data...

Comment: @Mat'sMug I thought that too. But that's not the case...

Comment: @TimWilliams I thought about that too, so what I did is I started creating new Sheet for each text file `Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)` which I then deleted after processing each file `Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Delete` And it still only happening to that one file.

Comment: I think you'll need to make a way for people to reproduce your problem.

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2511-excel-prevent-text-to-column.html shows how to stop the auto text-to-columns: if that's being "remembered" at the workbook level then adding a new sheet might not help.  Have you tried putting the text into a new workbook instead of a new sheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams I just tried it... same thing. Is it possible that this one file has some formatting that might be causing Excel to behave like that? (one of those invisible formatting codes?)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I just tried the `textstream` by using the `WriteLine` method... same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was causing this problem! I opened the text file in a Word and noticed that the line that was abruptly cut had some weird symbols (four empty squares?) that were not visible in Notepad. So then I started opening all the other files in Word and neither one of them had them.
So then I started reading about "*non printable characters*" and came up with this solution... I'm replacing each `ASCII(0) (NULL)` character with a blank space.
I'm posting it in case someone else will have to deal with a problem like that:

```
MyFolder = "C:\Test\"
StrFile = Dir(MyFolder & "tempfile.txt")

Open MyFolder & StrFile For Binary As #1
MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
Get #1, , MyData
Close #1
strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

LineNumber = 1
For Each sData In strData
    sData = Replace(sData, Chr(0), " ")
    Range("A" & LineNumber).Value = sData 'Now it works!!
    LineNumber = LineNumber + 1
Next
```

Thank you for your help everybody!

Answer (score 0):

(Need formatting of an answer, but this is really a comment)

Give this a try:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim sFolderPath As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sFullText As String
    Dim aOutput() As String

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sFolderPath = "C:\Test\"
    sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "tempfile.txt")
    sFullText = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sFolderPath & sFileName).ReadAll

    aOutput = Split(sFullText, vbCrLf)
    With Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aOutput) - LBound(aOutput) + 1)
        .Value = Application.Transpose(aOutput)
    End With

End Sub
```

If that still fails, you'll need to provide the problem text file.

Comment: How could I provide that file?

Comment: @kurtz Can either edit your question and copy/paste its contents to the bottom of the question as a code block so that we can copy/paste it into a text file, or you'd have to upload the text file somewhere like google drive or dropbox and then provide the link.